# jQuery Autosave plugin use is buggy. Uncaught ReferenceError: myObject is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using [this jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-autosave/source/browse/trunk/jquery.autosave.js?r=3) which promises to pass on javascript objects to a PHP file. The plugin's code in included below

I'm getting this error in chrome console log:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myObject is not defined

```
$.each($.autoSave.object, function (obj, handler) {
if ( $.toJSON( eval( obj ) ) != $.autoSave._oldObjString[ obj ] && !$.autoSave.saving[ obj ] )
```

How can I fix this?

I'm passing the myObject object which according to Chrome console.log is

```
Object {john: "13:55 30/1"}
```

This is how I'm using it.

```
<script>
 **jquery.json.js is here
 **Bellow Autosave jQuery Plugin Code is here**
</script>

<script>
  $(window).load(function() {
     myObject = {};
     myObject[id] = date;
     $.autoSave.object = { 'myObject' : 'save.php'};
  });
</script>
```

This is the code for autoSave jQuery plugin:

```
 /* autoSave jQuery plugin - automatically save a js object to a server-side script
 **  CONFIG -- place in your document.ready function two possible config settings:
 **  $.autoSave.object = {'obj1':'/handler.php',..}; // REQUIRED - object of object:saver pairs - object names must work with eval()
 **  jquery.json.js plugin required
 */
(function($) {// setup the interval function as singleton via document.ready.
$(function() {
   $.autoSave.intervalId = $.autoSave.intervalId || window.setInterval(function() {
      if (typeof $.autoSave == 'function') $.autoSave($.autoSave.callback);
   }, 800);
});
$.autoSave = function(callback) {
   // the jquery.json.js plugin must be included && autosave object must be initialized
   if (typeof($.toJSON) != 'function' || typeof $.autoSave.object == 'undefined') return false;
   $.autoSave._oldObjString = $.autoSave._oldObjString || {};
   $.autoSave.saving = $.autoSave.saving || {};
   // loop through each autoSave obj, detect changes and save if so - through closures of $.each()
   $.each($.autoSave.object, function(obj, handler) {
      // only if the object has changed value in any way - this is a semi-expensive operation
      if ($.toJSON(eval(obj)) != $.autoSave._oldObjString[obj] && !$.autoSave.saving[obj])
      // formulate a simple POST with the JSON serialized data to save in the session
      $.ajax({
         data: 'saveObject=' + escape($.toJSON(eval(obj))),
         type: 'POST',
         beforeSend: function() {
            $.autoSave.saving[obj] = true;
         },
         success: function() {
            $.autoSave._oldObjString[obj] = $.toJSON(eval(obj));
            if (typeof callback == 'function') callback(eval(obj));
            $.autoSave.saving[obj] = false;
         },
         url: handler,
         error: function() {
            $.autoSave.intervalId = window.clearInterval($.autoSave.intervalId);
         }
      });
   });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `myObject` is supposed to be the name of a variable (object) you want to save.  Where do you define `myObject`?

Comment: it's been defined above the $.autoSave.object call. I've edited the question to reflect the coding structure better